# Is there a name for this technique for evaluating non-homogeneous linear recurrences?

Tags: matrices, recurrence-relations

In the course of answering [a question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41111249/using-matrices-to-find-the-number-of-different-ways-to-write-n-as-the-sum-of-1/41112123#41112123), I stumbled on a technique for evaluating certain non-homogeneous linear recurrence relations that's related to, but a bit different than, a technique I'd seen before.

As a motivation, suppose you want to compute $F_n$, then $n$th Fibonacci number. Using the fact that

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
F_{k+1} \\
F_k
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
F_{k+2} \\
F_{k+1}
\end{bmatrix},
$$
we can compute $F_{k+1}$ by computing
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}^k
\begin{bmatrix}
F_{1} \\
F_0
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
F_{k+1} \\
F_{k}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and looking at the first component of the resulting vector. That middle matrix can be raised to the $k$th power in time $O(\log k)$ using [repeated squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring), so this gives a fast algorithm for computing Fibonacci numbers.

The observation I had came up for solving a recurrence that's somewhat similar to this one:

$$A_0 = 1$$
$$A_{n+1} = 2A_n + F_n$$

This recurrence relation isn't homogeneous, but we can still set up a matrix equation like this one:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
A_{k+1} \\
F_{k+1} \\
F_{k}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
2A_{k+1} + F_{k+1} \\
F_{k+1} + F_{k} \\
F_{k + 1}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
A_{k+2} \\
F_{k+2} \\
F_{k + 1}
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

This gives us the same sort of "shifting" as before and works by essentially solving two parallel, interrelated recurrences at the same time. As a result, we can compute $A_{k+1}$ efficiently by computing

$$\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}^k
\begin{bmatrix}
A_{1} \\
F_{1} \\
F_{0}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
A_{k+1} \\
F_{k+1} \\
F_{k}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and looking at the first component. This can again be computed in time $O(\log n)$.

More generally, it seems like any linear recurrence relation of the form

$$A_{n+1} = \sum_{i = 0}^k{c_i A_{n-i}} + L_n$$

where $L_n$ is some other term that can also be expressed as a linear recurrence relation can be evaluated at an arbitrary point in $O(\log n)$ matrix multiplications.

I seriously doubt that I'm the first person to come up with this, but I haven't come across this technique before anywhere. Is this a known technique? Does it have a name?

Comment: That $2 \times 2$ matrix should be
$$
\pmatrix{1&1\\1&0}
$$

Comment: Are you familiar with theorem that you can solve the homogeneous and non-homogeneous part separately and then add them together ? Would that help?

Comment: I would categorize this (not unusual) technique, which adds a dimension to the issue, as "projective". More precisely, it is the usual way to transform an affine relationship into a linear one.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks! Fixed.

Comment: @GFauxPas I haven't seen that technique before. By any chance do you have a link I can follow on that topic?

Comment: @templatetypedef I may not get to my computer today. Try Googling "eigensequences"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\ Sf_n = f_{n +1}\,$ be the $n$-shift operator.

In operator form your nonhomogeneous recurrence is $\ (S-2) A_n = F_n$

We can make it homogeneous by multiplying it by $\,S^2-S-1,\,$ the annihilator of $\,F_n,\,$yielding

$$\begin{align} 0 \,&=\, (S^2\!-S-1)(S-2) A_n\\ &=\, (S^3-3S^2+S+2) A_n\\ &=\, P(S) A_n\end{align}$$

This is essentially what you have done by constructing that matrix. Indeed, computing its characteristic polynomial  yields $\, -P(S).$